Why natural map $M \rightarrow \prod M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ makes sense?
I am referring to this post where there is a natural map from  $A-$module $M \rightarrow \prod M_p$ for $p$ are maximal ideals of $A$.
I understand why the map is injective if it makes sense, but what I don't know is does it make sense, since the product here is the direct sum.
Specifically, post proves that any nonzero $m$ maps to some nonzero element. What guarantees that only finitely many nonzero coordinates exists? Since $m = 0$ in $M_p$ iff there exists $s \in A - p$ s.t $sm = 0$ iff $ann(m)\cap (A - p) \neq {\phi}$. Then why only finitely many exceptions to that condition can exist?

The direct product is not the direct sum. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product


since the product here is the direct sum

No. It is direct product. It even uses a different symbol "$\prod$" instead of standard "$\bigoplus$".
In general the map is not well defined for direct sum.

I made mistake of thinking if 'direct' is used, it cannot be 'like' 'Cartesian'.
